# How to make a view report different dimensions to layout than it actually is?

Tags: android

Like in the title: is there a way to create a custom view that reports different dimensions to it's layout parent, than it actually calculates in it's `onMeasure`?

I am trying to make a view that extends ImageView, that has a label under it, which should be ignored by all layouts (i.e. if I put two of these views under each other, the top view's label should just overlap the bottom one). Essentially the text label is drawn, but shouldn't be used in any layout calculations.

Comment: I'm not quite sure, but I think your view content is always drawn in its measure bounds, so if you return smaller measure results, you won't be able to draw the label.

Comment: In your custom view, you could over-ride the onMeasuredWidth() (or whatever those are called) to return whatever you would like...but you should re-think your solution, as you are complicating this (when things are hard to do in Android, it indicates, maybe you shouldn't be doing them)

Comment: When things are hard in Android, it usually means it's trying to prevent end users being stupid by disallowing developers to build certain edge-case functionality(a custom launcher in this case), in my experience. I must do it this way, for my use case there is no other alternative. For now I have to use a custom `ViewGroup` that ignores all children with a certain tag in it's layout computations, however that is not ideal because it only works when that layout is big enough to cover all the ignored views anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so it looks like this is impossibru. A workaround is to make a custom view that adjusts it's margins to match the required boundary. This works fine as long as the parent layout supports negative margins, but requires the view to be aware of it's parent(to get the appropriate `LayoutParams` instance) which in itself makes it a hacky solution.

Better way is to subclass a `ViewGroup` and make it calculate child sizes based on a separate view boundary supplied by child (when available, e.g. via interface like `implements CustomViewBounds` with a `Rect getViewBounds()` method), but that of course limits you to the usage of that class as a parent.

Anyway I expect this is a very isolated case, so doubt there are going to be many who need this functionality.

UPDATE:  The solution exists: see kris larson's answer, but it's not applicable in my context.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of an XML-only approach.  The key is to have `clipChildren` set to false on the parent view group and then translate the text view down by it's height.  A little hacky, but if your texts are predictable this is probably better than coding your own custom view group component.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:clipChildren="false">


    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/square"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="This is the text"
            android:translationY="40dp"/>

    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2">

    </FrameLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

The weights are there just to give the `FrameLayout` with the `TextView` some room to render the `TextView` below its bottom.  You can see how this all works right in the Android Studio layout designer.

Comment: Perhaps. I can't test it now, but I'll check tomorrow.

Comment: Not this couldn't work, sadly. This simple makes items inside `FrameLayout` overlap each other. What I need is a view that can be placed e.g. inside `RelativeLayout`, which would have a boundary that is different from it's actual rendered size. So for example, if I set it to be aligned above another view, it's text will overlap that other view. Right now, `RelativeLayout` will align the bottom of the text with the view below.

Comment: Oh.  Now I understand what you are trying to do.  Not impossibru.  See my updated answer.

Comment: Yes this does work, but in my context this is way too complex a layout - I may be having up to a hundred of these with different sizes and other attributes. Nevertheless, it's as close to the answer as it gets, even if it's not applicable in my context, so I'll upvote it.